# UIButton state won't change

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.3

In the header file I've declared the following for a UIButton with separate images for the states "normal", "highlighted", and "selected":

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *checkbox;

-(IBAction)selectButton;
```

and connected them to the button in the xib.  The implementation is as follows:

```
- (IBAction)selectButton
{
    self.checkbox.selected=!self.checkbox.selected;
}
```

During run, when the user touches the button, it goes to the "highlighted" image, but then it goes right back to the "normal" image rather than changing to the "selected" image.  I've added `NSLog(@"selected:  %d",self.checkbox.selected` in `selectButton` on both sides of the code and I get `0` both before and after.  What am I doing wrong, that touching the button doesn't change the state to `selected`?

Comment: Are you getting more than one call to `selectButton` on a single tap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by the following?

```
self.checkbox.selected=!self.checkbox.selected;
```

It's a condition (which is always false). Something similar to `if (1 != 1) {..}`.

You probably mean one of the following:

```
self.checkbox.selected = YES;
self.checkbox.disabled = YES;
self.checkbox.highlighted = YES;
```

(or `NO`).

Comment: Of COURSE.  Duh.  Because that's the sort of thing that I miss....  What I meant (and what ended up working) was: (self.checkbox.selected)=(!self.checkbox.selected);  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)selectButton
{


if (check.isSelected) {
    self.checkbox.selected=NO;
 }else
{
    self.checkbox.selected=YES;

}

}
```